# CL57T stepper driver not working in closed loop mode

Tags: stepper-driver, closed-loop

I've bought https://www.ebay.de/itm/393715526356 CL57T with NEMA 23 and it works well in open-loop mode but in closed-loop it goes into 7-blink error mode.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/BnkV1mTWC3q8ZEC99

As per manual, this means the encoder is wired incorrectly. I triple checked the color coding and even tried connecting encoder using different wires but the problem remained:

[image]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/GZoCvSBxdAJab4YG7

[Here's the code I'm using](https://gist.github.com/kachurovskiy/2a82f0afa9eed04b754279835e187b60), probably the only noteworthy thing there is triggering pulses by going high-low-high:

```
  digitalWrite(STEP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(STEP, HIGH);
```

Here's the manual for the driver: https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/CL57T_V4.0.pdf

Any ideas how to run this motor in closed-loop mode? Thank you. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Problem found, I had red and blue motor leads swapped in the driver, it was "stalling" because it was driving in the "wrong" direction. The correct wiring:

[image]